# Transform mixed text and nodes before, after and between a given sibling

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I am looking to fix some XML that has block level elements in paragraph tags.  The XML is something like:

```
<p>
   This is some text with <tag>some other markup</tag> in it that also needs transformation
   <div>
     Oh no here is a block element
   </div>
   It is even worse as <i>there is more content</i> between that needs transform
   <div>
     more block content
   </div>
   more text
</p>
```

So the pattern is arbitrary text and nodes with mixed in block level elements.  It can be any number of these divs and other text in here so answers using indexes won't work for all cases.

I am wishing to transform this to

```
 <p>This is some text with <transformed-tag>some other markup</transformed-tag> in it that also needs transformation</p>
 <div>Oh no here is a block element</div>
 <p>It is even worse as <i>there is more content</i> between that needs transform</p>
 <div>more block content</div>
 <p>more text</p>
```

So essentially I want to capture all descendants of `p` that are not in the `div` tag and wrap each with `p` tags while preserving the order of the text and the divs.  I have tried everything but am not certain how to capture the text between the divs.  I have been able to transform the data from the first blob to the first div and then the data from the last div to the end using

```
<xsl:template match="p[following::div]">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="p[preceding::div]">
   <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Update: Made output match.  The text that is being outputted in the divs and p tags needs to have templates applied to it too as there can be elements nested in there that need style applied to them.

Comment: Do you actually want to get rid of the `<i>` and `<b>` tags?

Comment: @MarcusRickert I want to apply-templates to any tags that are not in the divs as they need transformation and could be nested too.  So wrap all text/nodes outside of divs with <p> and apply-templates to contents.

Comment: None of the expected output text is in the input text. Could you update the question to use the input text and give the correct output result?

Comment: @ThomasW. I adjusted it to make it more clear.  Before I was just trying to stress that the descendants of the newly wrapped text needs transform too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so what am I missing here?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/p">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]" mode="first"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="div[1]"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="first">
    <p>
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::div)]" mode="next"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="next">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::div)]" mode="next"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag" mode="next">
    <transformed-tag>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </transformed-tag>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::div)]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::div)]" mode="first"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following::div[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```